# Crear un nuevo elemento en una array en c#

Tags: c#, array, asp.net-mvc, lista

quisiera que me ayudaran a como podría generar un nuevo objeto dentro de la lista de Product, es un simple CRUD

```
using ProductsApp.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ProductsApp.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        Product[] products = new Product[]
            {
                new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1  },
                new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.5M  },
                new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardwarw", Price = 16.99M  }
            };



        public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return products;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
        {
            var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(product);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Es decir, estás preguntado como hacer una función a la que le pasas un Product y la función lo añade al array products. Una función como: void AddProduct( Product p)

Answer (score 2):

Los arrays no son adecuados para añadir y quitar elementos en tiempo de ejecución. Si necesitas ese tipo de comportamiento, lo mejor es usar otro tipo de datos, por ejemplo en tu caso `List<Product>`.

Si aun asi te empeñas en utilizar arrays, puedes utilizar `Array.Resize` que te permite hacer mas grande el array y luego añadir el elemento nuevo, aunque debes tener en cuenta que es bastante costoso y que realmente el array se vuelve a construir.

```
Array.Resize(ref products, products.Length + 1);
products[products.Length - 1] = product;
```